# Rock Paper Scissors Game Best 2 out of 3 with Loops

Tags: java

The code is below. My program runs smoothly except for two issues. It does not play for just three rounds and I need it to play for just 3 rounds and determine a winner based off of whoever won at least once during the three rounds despite ties (if it comes down to that scenario randomly). It plays until there is a 2 to 1 winning ratio for either the player or the computer. I do not want it to run continuously like this. The other issue is that once a final winner is declared, the line “Enter rock, paper, or scissors” appears again, and it is not needed there. How do I go about fixing these two issues? Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * 
 * @author Chloe Harris
 *
 */
public class RockPaperScissorsGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //Prompt user to enter rock, paper, or scissors
        //Compare random value
        while(true){
        int wins = 0;
        int losses = 0;
        int rnd = 0;
        int USER = 0;

        System.out.print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3! \n"
            + "Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");


        // Plays 3 rounds before terminating
        while(rnd<3) {

            Random GAME = new Random();
            int PC = 1+GAME.nextInt(3);

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            int SCISSOR, ROCK, PAPER;
            ROCK = 1;
            PAPER = 2;
            SCISSOR= 3;

            String USER_Input =  keyboard.next();
            if(USER_Input.equals("Rock"))  {
                   USER = 1;
            }
            if(USER_Input.equals("Paper")) {
                   USER = 2;
            }
            if(USER_Input.equals("Scissors")) {
                   USER = 3;
            }



            //If the user enters a value greater then 3 or less than 1 it will terminate the program
            //and display an error message
            while (USER > 3 || USER < 1) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect value entered.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }

            if(USER == PC){
                if(USER == SCISSOR){
                    System.out.println("Scissors v Scissors! Tie!");

            }
                if(USER == ROCK){
                    System.out.println("Rock v Rock! Tie!");
            }
                if(USER == PAPER){
                    System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!");
            }
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
            }
            //Player wins

            if(USER == SCISSOR)
                if(PC == PAPER){
                System.out.println("Scissors v Paper! Player Wins!");
                wins++;
                rnd++;
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
            }
            //Computer wins
            else if(PC == ROCK){
                System.out.println("Scissors v Rock! Computer Wins!");
                losses++;
                rnd++;
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
            }
            //Player wins

            if(USER == ROCK)
                if(PC == SCISSOR ){
                System.out.println("Rock v Scissor! Player Wins!");
                wins++;
                rnd++;
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
            }   
            //Computer wins
            else if (PC == PAPER){
                System.out.println("Rock v Paper! Computer Wins!");
                losses++;
                rnd++;
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
            }

            //Player Wins
            if(USER == PAPER)
                if(PC == ROCK){
                System.out.println("Paper v Rock! Player Wins!");
                wins++;
                rnd++;
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
                }
            //Computer Wins 
            else if (PC == SCISSOR){
                System.out.println("Paper v Scissors! Computer Wins!");
                losses++;
                rnd++;
                System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
            }

            }

            if(wins>losses){
                System.out.println("The Player Wins!");
            }if(losses>wins){
                System.out.println("The Computer Wins!");
            }
            System.out.println("Play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");
            Scanner YN = new Scanner(System.in);

            String YN_String = YN.next();
            if(YN_String.equals("Yes") || YN_String.equals("yes")){
            }if(YN_String.equals("No") || YN_String.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println ("Goodbye!");
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The requirements are detailed as followed: The player can enter either “rock”, “paper”, or “scissors”.
If the player enters anything other than that the computer automatically gets a point
The computer randomly selects one of the gestures
Use the Random type to make this easier
Also make sure you import java.util.Random
You can use randomly selected integers to represent the gestures
For each combination either the computer scores a point, the player scores a point, or they score neither on draws.
Rock vs Paper = Paper wins
Paper vs Scissors = Scissors wins
Scissors vs Rock = Rock wins

Comment: And after 3 rounds the winner or a tie is declared
The player is then asked whether or not they want to play again, and if they do the whole process starts over.

Comment: What did you try? And why did it not work?

Comment: Also, `YN_String.equals("Yes") || YN_String.equals("yes")` can be simplified to `YN_String.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")`

Comment: Thank you so much! This really should've been a no brainer.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks like it should work the way you want it to, aside from the fact that in the case of ties, you aren't incrementing the round counter:

```
        if(USER == PC){
            if(USER == SCISSOR){
                System.out.println("Scissors v Scissors! Tie!");
                rnd++;
            }
            if(USER == ROCK){
                System.out.println("Rock v Rock! Tie!");
                rnd++;
            }
            if(USER == PAPER){
                System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!");
                rnd++;
            }
            System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
            System.out.print("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" \n");
        }
```

As a side note, you could take out the `rnd++;` from each individual result, and have it increase every time you get input from the user, since you want it to increase no matter what.

Your second issue stems from the fact that you're prompting for new input every time you receive input, after you tell the user the result, including the ending result.  You could fix this by removing the prompt command from the individual results and placing it at the beginning of your while loop instead.  Note that if you do this, you may also want to remove the prompt from your welcome message as well, or it will prompt twice at the beginning: once in the welcome message, and again when the while loop starts immediately after.

Comment: Thanks! You're literally a grade saver!

Comment: I do have one more question and that is how do I get the program to automatically give the computer a win when an input aside from rock, paper, or scissors is entered. Also, when I ask the play if they want to play again and they say yes, how do I get only the println "Enter rock papers, scissors" and not the "Welcome..."? Thank you. Th new edited code is below:

Comment: I've posted suggestions on what I think needs to be changed for your new issues as a comment on your edited code.  I can't actually check it right now, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * 
 * @author Chloe Harris
 *
 */
public class RockPaperScissorsGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //Set integers for wins, losses, rounds, and user
        while(true){
            int wins = 0;
            int losses = 0;
            int round = 0;
            int Player = 0;

            //Plays 3 rounds before terminating
            //Prompt user to input Rock Paper Scissors
            System.out.print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3! \n");

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            while(round<3) {
                System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\"");
                Random Game = new Random();
                int Computer = 1+Game.nextInt(3);

                int Scissors, Rock, Paper;
                Rock = 1;
                Paper = 2;
                Scissors= 3;

                String UserInput =  keyboard.next();
                if(UserInput.equals("Rock"))  {
                    Player = 1;
                }
                if(UserInput.equals("Paper")) {
                    Player = 2;
                }
                if(UserInput.equals("Scissors")) {
                    Player = 3;
                }

                //If the user enters a value greater then 3 (Scissors) or less than 1 (Rock)
                //it will terminate the program and display an error message
                while (Player > 3 || Player < 1) {
                    losses++;
                    round++;
                    System.out.println("Not a valid input! Computer wins");
                    System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");

                }

                //Establish tie scenarios using if statements
                if(Player == Computer){
                    if(Player == Scissors){
                        System.out.println("Scissors v Scissors! Tie!");
                        round++;
                    }
                    if(Player == Rock){
                        System.out.println("Rock v Rock! Tie!");
                        round++;
                    }
                    if(Player == Paper){
                        System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!");
                        round++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");

                }

                //Establish the various winning scenarios using if and else if statements
                //Player wins
                if(Player == Scissors)
                    if(Computer == Paper){
                        System.out.println("Scissors v Paper! Player Wins!");
                        wins++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
                //Computer wins
                    else if(Computer == Rock){
                        System.out.println("Scissors v Rock! Computer Wins!");
                        losses++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
                //Player wins
                if(Player == Rock)
                    if(Computer == Scissors ){
                        System.out.println("Rock v Scissors! Player Wins!");
                        wins++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }   
                //Computer wins
                    else if (Computer == Paper){
                        System.out.println("Rock v Paper! Computer Wins!");
                        losses++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
                //Player Wins
                if(Player == Paper)
                    if(Computer == Rock){
                        System.out.println("Paper v Rock! Player Wins!");
                        wins++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");

                    }
                //Computer Wins 
                    else if (Computer == Scissors){
                        System.out.println("Paper v Scissors! Computer Wins!");
                        losses++;
                        round++;
                        System.out.println("Player has won " + wins + " times and the computer has won " + losses + " times");
                    }
            }

            //Determine final winner using if statements
            //Ask if player would like to play again by setting up string 
            if(wins>losses){
                System.out.println("The Player Wins!");
            }if(losses>wins){
                System.out.println("The Computer Wins!");
            }
            System.out.println("Play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");
            Scanner YesNo = new Scanner(System.in);

            String YesNo_String = YesNo.next();
            if(YesNo_String.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))    {
            }if(YesNo_String.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))    {
                System.out.println ("Goodbye!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your check for giving the computer a win on invalid input is currently in a while loop of its own, so it begins to loop infinitely as soon as there is invalid input.  An `if` check should be sufficient for what you want.  As for the initial prompt issue, if you don't want the welcome message to display for every game, you should move it outside of your large while loop, so that it will only run once whenever you start your program, since the loop if where your game code is.